# Can this be a DoS Attack?

Tags: linux, brute-force, denial-of-service

When I'm checking my log, I found like 15k events of " PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 "

I know this might be normal, and considered as Brute-Force attack, but can it be classified as DoS attempt?

Sample of the log:

```
| 8864611 | eros     | 2014-08-11 18:18:38 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8865352 | eros     | 2014-08-11 18:46:59 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8865364 | eros     | 2014-08-11 18:47:13 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8865693 | eros     | 2014-08-11 19:00:39 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8865700 | eros     | 2014-08-11 19:01:55 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8865706 | eros     | 2014-08-11 19:02:11 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8865716 | eros     | 2014-08-11 19:02:28 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8866965 | eros     | 2014-08-11 19:59:47 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8867068 | eros     | 2014-08-11 20:00:18 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8896353 | eros     | 2014-08-12 17:31:33 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8896363 | eros     | 2014-08-12 17:31:49 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8901992 | eros     | 2014-08-12 21:40:48 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8902001 | eros     | 2014-08-12 21:41:03 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 |
| 8902007 | eros     | 2014-08-12 21:41:18 |  PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
```

Comment: To me the interval between the log file entries are too long for a Denial of Service attack. Like you said this seems more like a brute force attack.

Comment: you probably know [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/588297/pam-servicesshd-ignoring-max-retries); denyhosts or fail2ban might help in blocking malicious stuff out

Comment: True I do know, I was just analyzing the data and check if there was any other potential attacks in addition for Brute-Force attack

Comment: Have a look at this: http://serverfault.com/questions/588297/pam-servicesshd-ignoring-max-retries

Comment: Install fail2ban and monitor it. You can change the port number of ssh to something bigger than 20000. You can limit access to ssh to a limited list of IP-numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this were a denial of service attack, you'd be seeing those 15k messages covering less than an hour -- probably far less.  This is just the botnet-based brute-force attack on SSH passwords that constitutes part of the "background noise" of the Internet.

Make sure you're using strong passwords (or better yet, key-based authentication) and that you've disabled root login over SSH, and don't worry about it.

Comment: Nice phrase "background noise" of the internet :)